# Opsworks recipe bash failed

Tags: docker, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, recipe

I have a problem with this recipe

```
Chef::Log.info("***************** Deploying ***************")
bash "docker-cleanup" do
    user "root"
    returns [0, 1]
    code <<-EOH
        if docker ps | grep scheduler1;
        then
            docker stop scheduler1
            sleep 3
            docker rm scheduler1
        fi
        if docker ps -a | grep scheduler1;
        then
            docker rm scheduler1
        fi 
        if docker images | grep vouchdocker;
        then
            docker rmi $(sudo docker images | grep -m 1 vouchdocker | awk {'print $3'})
        fi
    EOH
end

Chef::Log.info('*********** Docker cleaned, pulling and running ****************')

bash "docker-login" do
    user "root"
    returns [0, 1]
    code <<-EOH
        docker login -u someuser -p somepassword
    EOH
end

bash "docker-run" do
    user "root"
    returns [0, 1]
    code <<-EOH
        docker run --name somename -p 6001:8001 -e ENV=_PRODUCTION  --restart always someregistery/someimage:latest
    EOH
end

Chef::Log.info('********** All set! ***************')
```

The recipe works fine except the process is stuck, it looks like it doesn't complete and stalls somewhere.

It stays in 'running_setup' state, anyone knows why?

Comment: Do you have local logs (not jus the Chef logs) to see if you have a command being called repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out recipe works just fine, altho the process took a really long time, not sure why. But then recipe failed, turns out because the returns [0, 1], the bash script returns 2, changing it to [0, 1, 2] fix the problem. thanks!